# ReportViewer.ServerReport.refresh() from Client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

i'm trying to refresh a report with this line:

```
<% ReportViewer.ServerReport.refresh() %>
```

This line is written in the ASPX file. I can't write it in the CS file for some reason.

I get an error: "Viewer Control Object is in a read only state".

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Try moving the `Refresh()` method in `OnPreRenderComplete` event. Can you explain in what event that method want to be used?

Comment: hey, i want to set parameters and to refresh the report.

Comment: Now, the refresh() in Javascript function not in PageLoad

Comment: Begin with `var rp = new ReportParameter(...)`, set `ReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp })` and then `ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh()`. I don't know if the `ReportViewer` can accept parameter settings from client-side JS function.

Comment: hey, thanks. this what i did but i got an error "Viewer Control Object is in a read only state"